# Web app installation wizard can't write into data/config.php file

Tags: 18.04, permissions, apache2, configuration, open-source

Informations below may allow to track why the installation wizard returns:
**“Cannot write into data/config.php file. Please delete this file“**.

**MATERIAL**

---

**SERVER :** Linux distro Ubuntu 18.04 remote VPS / apache2 / PHP 7.2 ;
**MYSQL :** ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2 ; **CPANEL :** ISPCconfig v3.1.13

**APPLICATION**

---

**Epesi app :** Version : Released /v1.8.2.6/Release 1.8.2-20171019.zip ;
**ISPconfig panel :** web root dir and db created for Epesi app ; PHP 7.2 (php-fpm) activated for Epesi app ; db and web root directory access allowed to non-root ssh user ; **Epesi app :** new installation using compressed file ; directory contents FTP uploaded to web root dir ; data dir read/write switch to 777 on FTP connection (by non-root ssh user)

**INSTALLATION WIZARD**

---

French language selected - OK > next page (all boxes checked)... OK >
next page: db configuration OK > next page: **cannot write into "data/congig.php“** ; CORRECTION : **read/write access of “config.php“ file switched to 777**

**Installation wizard relaunched :** ... db configuration OK > next page result: **cannot write into "data/congig.php“. Please delete this file**

**Epesi app troubleshooting info page :** http://www.epesi.org/Troubleshooting

**Any idea of why the Epesi installation wizard can't write the config.php file?**

Answer (score 0):

As info error "Cannot Write into data/congig.php", You can check permission Of User setup and allow permission for folder data with command:

```
chmod -R 777 data
```

If you want change permission of User with command:

```
chown -R user:user data
```

So maybe it will help you.